# Run tests in TFS 2010 with a different identity

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tfs, impersonation

Is it possible to run the tests on TFS 2010 with a different identity ?

The code being tested require higher privileges ( Active Directory, Filesystem manipulations) than the ones the current account has.
Right now there there is impersonation in the code but I want to get rid of it as the calling website will have the impersonation active.

Thanks !
Vincent

Comment: unit testing and active directory manipulation don't seem to go together that well.

Comment: Never had any troubles so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Test agent, Test Controller and MSTEST FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2010/10/24/test-agent-test-controller-and-mstest-faq.aspx):

> *Will Test Agents allow you to impersonate another user? Or does the
>   Test Agent always kick of tests as the user its configured start up
>   as?*
>
> There is no built in support for impersonation, so by default tests
>   run under the identity of the test agent.  If this is something you
>   really need, you could write a unit test extension that does the
>   impersonation for you.

You can potentially also turn this behavior into your advantage: run an MSTest agent under an elevated account and dispatch your test runs to be executed by this MSTest agent. To configure this, please read: [Create Test Settings to Run Automated Tests from Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx). This will allow you to run your test to be executed under the account ofn desire, without having to explicitly impersonate your user all the time.